# Type mismatch error in a scala for comprehension

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I am writing generators for the following ADTs. Idea is to generate the Blocks with random data. I am having a compiler error `Type mismatch: expected: Seq[Field], actual:Gen[Field]` in the `blockGen` method. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

The error is with `fields` on the last line of this method i.e. `yield Block(id, fields)`.

```
def blockGen(b: Block): Gen[Block] = for {
    id <- b.blockId
    fields <- b.fields.map(f => fieldGen(f))
} yield Block(id, fields)
```

**ADT**

```
trait Data {}

trait Field extends Data {
  val name: String
  val value: String
}

case class StringField(name: String, value: String) extends Field
case class NumberField(name: String, value: String) extends Field
case class Block(blockId: Field, fields: Seq[Field]) extends Data
```

**Generators**

```
def blockGen(b: Block): Gen[Block] = for {
    id <- b.blockId
    fields <- b.fields.map(f => fieldGen(f))
  } yield Block(id, fields)

def fieldGen(fieldType: Field): Gen[Field] = {
    for {
      f <-
      fieldType match {
        case _: NumberField => numGen
        case _: StringField => strGen
      }
    } yield f
  }

val strGen: Gen[StringField] = for {
    name <- Gen.identifier
    value <- Gen.alphaStr
  } yield StringField(name, value)

val numGen: Gen[NumberField] = for {
    name <- Gen.identifier
    value <- Gen.numStr
  } yield NumberField(name, value)
```

Comment: What line is generating that message? (Really, obviously, the question is what identifier is having the type mismatch)

Comment: @GreenAsJade add the offending line. Please see EDIT section

Comment: `fields` is an _element_ of `Seq[Gen[Field]]`, i.e. `Gen[Field]`, while `Block` constructor expects `Seq[Field]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by: `fieldGen(f)` return type is `Gen[Field]`, but your `Block` `fields` type is `Seq[Field]`, so compiler throw `type mismatch`.

Solution:

1. change `def fieldGen(fieldType: Field): Gen[Field]` to `def fieldGen(fieldType: Field): Seq[Field]`, or change `Block` fields type to `Gen[Feild]`
2. create implicit conversion for `Gen` to `Seq`, like:

   ```
   implicit def genToSeq[T](s: Gen[T]): Seq[T] = ??? // implementation conversion.
   ```